# Adding a list of strings to a Realm managed object causes the app to crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In the following code, adding the "let members =" declaration causes the app to immediately crash on launch.

The crash is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and the stack trace points to Object.swift -> getNonIgnoredMirrorChildren

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class GroupSyncModel : Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var created : String?
    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    @objc dynamic var groupId : String // Primary key
    @objc dynamic var adminUserId : String?
    @objc dynamic var adminUserName : String?
    @objc dynamic var joinedAt : String?

    let members = List<String>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "groupId"
    }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this. I know it seems that your `members` property is the problem but it's actually the `groupId` property. `groupId` needs to have a default value.

Change this:

```
@objc dynamic var groupId : String
```

To this:

```
@objc dynamic var groupId : String = "SOME_DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE"
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much! Saved me so much frustration and time. Realm can be so sensitive : (

Comment: it saves me. Do you have any explanation why object with List<T> need a default primary key value ?

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to understand what is wrong with the `List<CustomObject>`, but it just didn't like the empty `id`!!! Mindblowing!! Thank you Rob.